# Неправильно работает AtomicInteger в многопоточном счетчике

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть обычный многопоточный счетчик. Если я использую обычные переменные типа `int`, то все работает правильно. Но если использую `AtomicInteger`, ничего не работает правильно. В чем моя ошибка?

Работающий класс:

```
public class CASCount {

    private final AtomicReference<Integer> count = new AtomicReference<>(0);

    public void increment() {
        int current, next;
        do {
            current = count.get();
            next = current + 1;
        } while (!count.compareAndSet(current, next));
    }

    public int get() {
        return count.get();
    }
}
```

Не работающий класс:

```
private final AtomicReference<Integer> count = new AtomicReference<>(0);
    AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger();

    public void increment() {
        //Integer current, next;
        do {
           current.getAndAdd(count.get());
           next.incrementAndGet();
        } while (!count.compareAndSet(current.get(), next.get()));
    }

    public int get() {
        return count.get();
    }
```

Тест:

```
@Test
public void whenUseCASCount() throws InterruptedException {
    CASCount count = new CASCount();
    Thread one = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("one");
            count.increment();
        }
    });

    Thread two = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("two");
            count.increment();
        }
    });
    one.start();
    two.start();
    one.join();
    two.join();
    assertThat(count.get(), is(10));
}
```

Comment: Какой смысл использовать аж целых два `AtomicInteger` для того чтоб реализовать атомарный инкремент? Сам `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet` делает именно атомарный инкремент.

Comment: мне надо использовать метод compareAndSet поэтому

Comment: Значение `current`, сделанного полем, может в любой момент поменять любой поток - кажется, тут никакой метод `AtomicInteger` не спасёт

Comment: Уверен, что в задаче на использование `compareAndSet` не предполагается использование `AtomicInteger` ;)

Comment: предложили сделать через них вот тоже сижу ломаю голову постоянно второй поток нарушает всю работу

Comment: Либо ваша реализация использует факт, что они уже атомарные и compareAndSet роли не играет для вашего алгоритма, либо вы их используете для замены обычных `int` (т.е. делаете их локальными - иначе никак) - т.е. смысла особого в `AtomicInteger` нет.

Comment: просто интересно можно ли использовать 2 атомик интеджера в счетчике ?

Comment: Использовать для чего? Всегда можно прикрутить никак не влияющие на алгоритм переменные.

Comment: Для создания счетчика с использованием неблокирующего алгоритма cas

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126216/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-terasan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В не работающем классе логика существенно отличается от правильной. Правильная логика в решении с `int`-ами и ее суть в том, что (и это общая схема неблокирующих алгоритмов):

1. делается локальная копию разделяемой переменной
2. проводится операция по изменению локальной копии
3. атомарно делается замена значения, если оно все еще такое же как мы видели на шаге 1, иначе повторяем с шага 1

Во втором алгоритме куча проблем.

Первая проблема - это то, что `current` и `next` у вас разделяемые, а не локальные. Это значит, что их могут менять потоки одновременно, в отличии от правильного варианта, где они локальные.

Вторая проблема - это то, что логика шага 2 неправильная. Новое значение, которое хранится в `next` это не будет на 1 увеличенное значение в `count`. Во-первых,  значение в `next` зависит только от того, сколько раз был вызван цикл, а во вторых, так как это разделяемая переменная, то ее могут изменить другие потоки.

Можно заменить `int`-ы на `AtomicInteger`, только в этом совсем нет смысла - `int`-ы будут работать быстрее:

```
AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger();
do {
    current.set(count.get());
    next.set(current.get() + 1);
} while (!count.compareAndSet(current.get(), next.get()));
```

Ну и самое главное. `AtomicInteger` сам по себе реализует атомарный инкремент. Либо ваша реализация использует факт, что `AtomicInt` уже атомарный и `compareAndSet` роли не играет для вашего алгоритма, либо вы их используете для замены обычных `int` (т.е. делаете их локальными как в примере) - т.е. смысла особого в AtomicInteger нет.

Если суммировать: в задаче на `compareAndSet` не предполагается использовать `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: спасибо) не смог в чате пообщаться с вами к сожалению на эту тему